# Add value to Firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the timestamp feature to work on my app but it is not. I am building a chat app with `JSQMessagesViewController`. For every message a user sends, I want it to be displayed in my database.

So far this is the code I have:

```
//ADD A NEW MESSAGE

let timeStamp = NSNumber(value: Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970))

    private func addMessage(withId id: String, name: String, text: String, time: NSNumber) {
        if let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, displayName: name, text: text) {
            messages.append(message)
        }
    }

    override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!) {

        let itemRef = rootRef.child("messages").child("\(self.convoId!)").childByAutoId() // 1
        let messageItem = [ // 2
            "senderId": senderId!,
            "ReceiverId": senderDisplayName!,
            "text": text!,
            "timestamp": timeStamp,
            ] as [String : Any]

        itemRef.setValue(messageItem) // 3

        JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageSentSound() // 4

        finishSendingMessage() // 5
        isTyping = false
    }

 private func observeMessages() {
    // 1.
    let messageQuery = rootRef.child("messages/\(self.convoId!)").queryLimited(toLast: 25)

    // 2. We can use the observe method to listen for new
    // messages being written to the Firebase DB
    newMessageRefHandle = messageQuery.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

    // 3.
    let messageData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

    if let id = messageData["senderId"] as String!, let name = messageData["ReceiverId"] as String!, let text = messageData["text"] as String!, let time = messageData["timeStamp"] as Any!, text.characters.count > 0 {

    // 4.
    self.addMessage(withId: id, name: name, text: text, time: time as! NSNumber)

    // 5
    self.finishReceivingMessage()
  }
```

Here is a screenshot of my database:
[image]

Comment: What error do u have? or problem?

Comment: @VladPulichev the app crashed when I send a message. The message is sent to the database but does not show up in my view controller and I get a green line across `let messageData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>`

Comment: try to as! [String: AnyObject]. Has it helped?

Comment: @VladPulichev no it didn't help

Comment: Try to change "(snapshot) -> Void" to "snapshot"

Comment: @VladPulichev unfortunately it still crashes

Comment: with same error?

Comment: Can you please add to your question screenshot of database?

Comment: print(self.convoId!) - what value?

Comment: This is what it preints out : hx1DXeMFRU @VladPulichev

Comment: Hm..try to remove .queryLimited(toLast: 25).

Comment: @VladPulichev sadly still not working

Comment: Wait, I will think more..(

Comment: @VladPulichev ok thank you

Comment: @VladPulichev i figured it out, I just had to change `let messageData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>` to `let messageData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, Any>`

Comment: Can you please try with dictionary<string, anyobject> because it's the similar, that I have typed before?

Comment: I do always as! [String: AnyObject]. And it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
let messageData = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
```

Answer (score 0):

send timestamp direct no need to convert it to nsnumber

```
override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!) {

            let itemRef = rootRef.child("messages").child("\(self.convoId!)").childByAutoId() // 1
            let messageItem = [ // 2
                "senderId": senderId!,
                "ReceiverId": senderDisplayName!,
                "text": text!,
                "timestamp": NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970,
                ] as [String : Any]

            itemRef.setValue(messageItem) // 3

            JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageSentSound() // 4

            finishSendingMessage() // 5
            isTyping = false
        }
```

Comment: Do I still leave observeMessages() function as it is because when I do the app crashes